# .htaccess Rewriterule redirecting to a URL on the same domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect users to specific URLs. I want to create .htaccess rewriterules to accomplish this.

I would lke for these:

```
https://example.com/career_by_education
https://example.com/international_careers
https://example.com/major_careers
https://example.com/career
```

to transfer to:

```
https://example.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php
https://example.com/international_careers/international_careers.php
https://example.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php
https://example.com/career/career.php
```

I have tried many variations of rewrite rules to get this to work, and am successful if I want it to redirect to a different domain.

For example, the following (in .htaccss):

```
RewriteRule career_by_education   https://example2.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
RewriteRule international_careers   https:/example2.com/international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule major_careers   https://example2.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule career   https://example2.com/career/career.php [L,R]
```

Successfully transfer to (respectively):

```
https://example2.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php
https://example2.com/international_careers/international_careers.php
https://example2.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php
https://example2.com/career/career.php
```

But I want the redirect to be to the same domain (example.com), so I tried this (in this order):

```
RewriteRule career_by_education   https://example.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
RewriteRule international_careers  https://example.com/international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule major_careers   https://example.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule career   https://example.com/career/career.php [L,R]
```

When I enter any of these into the browser:

```
https://example.com/career_by_education
https://example.com/international_careers
https://example.com/major_careers
```

I always get this URL:

```
https://example.com/career/career.php
```

I tried to reverse the ordering of the RewriteRules to:

```
RewriteRule career   https://example.com/career/career.php [L,R]
RewriteRule major_careers   https://example.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule international_careers  https://example.com/international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule career_by_education   https://example.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
```

But the resulting URL is always:

```
https://example.com/career/career.php
```

I also tried to remove the full URL for the substitution, as follows:

```
RewriteRule career_by_education /career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
RewriteRule international_careers /international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule major_careers /major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule career /career/career.php [L,R]
```

But the result always redirects to this URL:

```
https://example.com/career/career.php
```

I have tried different expressions to see if it can work:

```
RewriteRule ^/career http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/career/career.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^/major_careers http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^/international_careers http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^/career_by_education http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
```

These all result in a "403 Forbidden" error - From the command line I ensured that I have a "index.php" in the root directory, and permissions were correct, with the following:

```
chmod 644 ~/public_html/.htaccess
chmod 755 ~/public_html
```

Then I tried these:

```
RewriteRule .*(?=major_careers) http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule .*(?=international_careers) http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule .*(?=career_by_education) http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
RewriteRule  .*(?=career) http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/career/career.php [L,R]
```

The resulting URL was always:

```
https://example.com/career/career.php
```

I don't understand why the pattern seems to work when redirecting to an outside URL, yet does not work if redirecting to a URL on the same domain.

Could anyone please help guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule career_by_education /career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
> RewriteRule international_careers /international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
> RewriteRule major_careers /major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
> RewriteRule career /career/career.php [L,R]
> ```

The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive (the *pattern*) is a regular expression. This is not an "exact string match". The problem with these rules is that the *pattern* also matches the redirected URL so would result in an endless "redirect loop", since the "regex" `career_by_education` matches that string *anywhere* in the URL-path.

You state that it always redirects to `/career/career.php` (the last rule above), but that's not possible with the rules as posted - due to the redirect-loop as mentioned above. However, it would happen if you reversed these directives (which you say you had also tried), since the first rule (that matches `career` only) would always match - but again, that is a redirect loop.

*Aside:* It might not trigger a redirect loop depending on your server config, eg. if requests for `.php` files are proxied to a CGI PHP engine.

You need to be more specific with the regex and match only the stated URLs. ie. You need to include *anchors* on the regex and match `career_by_education` *only* and not `career_by_education` *anywhere*.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^career_by_education$ /career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^international_careers$ /international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^major_careers$ /major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^career$ /career/career.php [L,R]
```

The order of these directives does not matter.

You don't necessarily need the scheme+hostname (ie. an absolute URL) in the *substitution* if you are redirecting to the same domain, however, it can help to reduce the number of redirects in the case of domain canonicalisation.

> I don't understand why the pattern seems to work when redirecting to an outside URL

Because the directives are not processed again after the redirect (you are now on a different server).

> ```
> RewriteRule .*(?=major_careers) http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
> ```

Using the unanchored positive lookahead is effectively the same as simply `major_careers`.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/career http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/career/career.php [L,R]
> RewriteRule ^/major_careers http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
> RewriteRule ^/international_careers http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
> RewriteRule ^/career_by_education http://consul64.wwwaz1-ts107.a2hosted.com/career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
> ```
>
> These all result in a "403 Forbidden" error

Because of the slash prefix, these rules would never match, so they wouldn't actually do anything.

---

**UPDATE:**

However, a "problem" with these redirects is that the URL you are redirecting from, eg. `/career_by_education` is also the name of the filesystem *directory* you are redirecting to. So, by default, mod_dir will attempt to append a trailing slash, so the rule doesn't match. The 403 likely results from the absence of a DirectoryIndex document in that directory. Strictly speaking, your URLs need to end in a trailing slash, or make the trailing slash optional in the regex (but that could result in a double redirect).

For example:

```
# Trailing slash is mandatory
RewriteRule ^career_by_education/$ /career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]

# Trailing slash is optional
RewriteRule ^career_by_education/?$ /career_by_education/careers-by-educational-level.php [L,R]
```

Although it would be preferable that the URL did not match the name of the directory in the first place.

Comment: @Ralph_J You're welcome. I've updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: Update*
I tried @MrWhite suggestion.  Two of them worked:

```
RewriteRule ^international_careers$ /international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^career$ /career/career.php [L,R]
```

However, the two others are giving me a "403 Forbidden" error. Do you think I need to change permissions? 
Directory permissions are 0755, and file permissions are 0644

Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Ralph_J The "problem" with these redirects is that the URL you are redirecting from, eg. `/career_by_education` is also the name of the filesystem _directory_ you are redirecting to. So mod_dir will attempt to append a trailing slash, so the rule doesn't match. The 403 likely results from the absence of a DirectoryIndex document in that directory. Strictly speaking, your URLs need to end in a trailing slash, or make the trailing slash optional. I'll update my answer...

Comment: **Update**

Not sure if it was the cache, but all works great now.  I used @MrWhite suggestions, as follows:
'
RewriteRule ^careers_by_education$ /career_by_education/careers_by_educational_level.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^international_careers$ /international_careers/international_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^major_careers$ /major_careers/academic_major_careers.php [L,R]
RewriteRule ^career$ /career/career.php [L,R]
'
Thank you for your help!

Comment: **Update**  In some cases I needed to use the '?' wildcard to make the final / optional for it to work.  In most cases I did not.  Thank you again @MrWhite !